# is this sentence deliberately scrambled

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

I work on some natural language processing resources, I encounter some weird sentences like this:

> Meanwhile, september housing starts, due Wednesday, are thought to have inched upward.

What is the meaning? is it an example of sentence scrambling where constituents of the sentence are scrambled?

Comment: No. **starts** is a plural noun. **due Wednesday** is a reduced clause modifying the noun.  **housing** is an adjective.  There is an ellipsis. **starts** is understood to mean "*the statistics relating to* starts".  "September housing starts" is a report relating to housing starts, i.e. the construction of new houses.

Comment: @TRomano - That should probably be an answer.

Comment: @stangdon: It's really just a misunderstanding on OP's part caused by the jargon. Not sure what the exact question would be.

Comment: "September housing starts" would be structurally akin to "nightly batch runs".

Answer (score 5):

Your sentence is not jumbled at all, it is very natural.

Taking apart your example

> Meanwhile
>   *in the meantime, during this time*
>
> September housing starts
>   *the subject of the sentence referring to a macro economic indicator*
>
> due Wednesday
>   *subordinate clause saying when the housing starts will be announced*
>
> are thought to have inched upward
>   *thought to have increased*

The main sentence you are interested in is

> September housing starts are thought to have inched upward

"Meanwhile" is a throw away word in your sentence and is useful only with some other context some where preceding your sentence.

"Due Wednesday" could appear anywhere in the sentence without loss of understanding

> Due Wednesday, September housing starts are thought to have inched upwards.
>   September housing starts are thought to have inched upwards, due Wednesday.

however it makes the sentence more awkward since "due Wednesday" specifically is referring to when the housing starts will be announced and is why it appears where it does.